# PHP - Sorting an array of data rows by price, date ASC, DESC, etc

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have an array of data which contains associative array rows and I would like to sort them by price,date etc. This cannot be done via SQL as these values are not in a database - I simply have a large array with the following example data:

```
$data[0] = array(
                 'id' => '2',
                 'price' => '400.00',
                 'date' => '2012-05-21',
                 ),
$data[1] = array(
                 'id' => '4',
                 'price' => '660.00',
                 'date' => '2012-02-21',
                 ),
$data[2] = array(
                 'id' => '8',
                 'price' => '690.00',
                 'date' => '2012-01-21',
                 )
```

etc..................

How can I sort this variable based on a select box such as sort by price ASC/DESC and date ASC/DESC

Sorry if this is simple - I am just so used to doing it via SQL that my mind has gone blank in this case.

Comment: Have you tried something yet? If not, the manual is a good start: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Thanks - I have looked at that already but it is just based on a single array isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may modify this function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#104464

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I needed and someone has done it already :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `usort` and define a function which sorts based on the key you want.

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php examples 2 and 4.

Comment: May include as reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php - look at Example #2 and #4

Answer (score 0):

Below sample code will sort it by id.

```
    $capitals = array(
     array(
             'id' => '2',
             'price' => '400.00',
             'date' => '2012-05-21',
             ),
     array(
             'id' => '1',
             'price' => '660.00',
             'date' => '2012-02-21',
             ),
     array(
             'id' => '0',
             'price' => '690.00',
             'date' => '2012-01-21',
             )

       );




  function cmp($a, $b)
  {
     return strcmp($a["id"], $b["id"]);
   }


 usort($capitals, "cmp");

 print_r($capitals);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `usort`:

```
function sortBySubKey(&$array, $key)
{
    return usort($array, create_function('$a,$b', 'if ($a["'.$key.'"] == $b["'.$key.'"]) return 0; return ($a["'.$key.'"] < $b["'.$key.'"]) ? -1 : 1;'));
}
```

You should make sure that your array holds valid values in the sense of this arithmetical comparision (`<`), eg. you should probably pass date as a unix timestamp for this, price as a float and so on...